# Create identifier based on some of the columns with shared data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the example below the column `sequence` should be a identifier for rows that share the same value in some of the columns - `compania, hrEntr, hrSaida, durJornada, durInterv, iniInterv, termInterv, sistema_horario, turno` - however it should not take into calculation one of the columns - `dia`.

So as described in the picture the first five rows share these columns so the `sequence` should be 1. Row 6, which doesn't share all of the previous values should have it's own `sequence` number set to 2.

[image]

I have worked with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...`  but it creates the opposite result i.e. it starts over when the matching columns stop.

Is there a way to create my desired result?

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need to be able to copy and paste your table schemas and data from your question. That's impossible with pictures. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and, regarding posting pictures, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use RANK() function. Check if this solve your need:

```
drop table if exists stackoverflowTbl;
/********************************************************** DDL+DML */
create table stackoverflowTbl(id int identity (1,1), txt int)
GO
insert stackoverflowTbl (txt) values (1),(1),(2),(1),(3),(22),(22)
GO
select * from stackoverflowTbl
GO
/********************************************************** solution */
select id,txt,
    ROW_Number () OVER (order by txt) - RANK ( ) OVER ( partition by txt order by id ) as MySequence 
from stackoverflowTbl
GO
```

Comment: You're answer is indeed correct however I believe that I described my problem poorly so I created a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540706/create-identifier-counter-based-on-some-shared-columns-and-seperate-based-on-oth

Comment: Well, i think that someone else already gave you the answer to the new question :-)