# Create identifier/counter based on some shared columns and seperate based on other columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create a calculated column based on a shared column but the calculated column should "restart" and be grouped based on a third column.

As described in the picture below Column 1 contains information belonging so a certain entity (some sort of ID). Column 2 contains the number of records that exists (1, 2 and 3). Column 3 contains the actual data (A, B or C) but the same value can exist between the three different records (separated by 
Column 2).

[image]

My previous process was discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530158/create-identifier-based-on-some-of-the-columns-with-shared-data?noredirect=1#comment90029288_51530158) but as I went along I believe that it wasn't originally explained correctly.

Is there a way to create my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [windowing function `DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with an `OVER()` clause:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Column1 INT,Column2 INT,Column3 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,1,'A')
                      ,(1,2,'A') 
                      ,(1,3,'B') 
                      ,(2,1,'A') 
                      ,(2,2,'A') 
                      ,(2,3,'B') 
                      ,(3,1,'A') 
                      ,(3,2,'B') 
                      ,(3,3,'V');

SELECT *
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3) AS ComputedColumn
FROM @tbl;
```

The `PARTITION BY` will re-start the counter for each new value in `column1`, while the `ORDER BY` defines the ranking.

### Hint: Do not paste pictures!

For your next question please follow my example to create a stand-alone example reproducing your issue and add the code you've tried yourself.